# How to check for files in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing BASH for school. The shell script should search for any text files called 'file' with a number on the end from 1-10. The program echoes to say if each file exists or not.

However, I just can't get the program to search for the files.

I made a number that increments by one. I can't find a way to put this variable between 'file' and '.txt'. What can I do?

```
#!/bin/sh
number=1
x=$(grep file<$number>.txt)
((number++))
while [ $number -le 10 ]
do
    if [ $x -eq true ]
    then
        echo file<$number>.txt exists
    else
        echo file<$number>.txt does not exist
    fi
    ((number++))
done
```

Comment: Using `bash` you can do: `for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do f="file$i.txt"; [[ -f $f ]] && echo "$f exists" || echo "$f does not exist"; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bash`:

```
$ touch file3.txt
$ for i in {1..10}; do file="file${i}.txt"; [[ -f $file ]] && echo "$file exists" || echo "$file doesn't exist"; done
file1.txt doesn't exist
file2.txt doesn't exist
file3.txt exists
file4.txt doesn't exist
file5.txt doesn't exist
file6.txt doesn't exist
file7.txt doesn't exist
file8.txt doesn't exist
file9.txt doesn't exist
file10.txt doesn't exist
```

Using `sh`:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 10`; do file="file${i}.txt"; if [ -f "$file" ]; then echo "$file exists"; else echo "$file doesn't exist"; fi; done
file1.txt doesn't exist
file2.txt doesn't exist
file3.txt exists
file4.txt doesn't exist
file5.txt doesn't exist
file6.txt doesn't exist
file7.txt doesn't exist
file8.txt doesn't exist
file9.txt doesn't exist
file10.txt doesn't exist
```